# Is there any religious text that asks Jews to dislike Muslims?

Tags: islam

Is there any religious text in Judaism that asks its followers to dislike Muslims? Dislike or even "hate" but NOT "fight" or "kill" as those are very different issues. To dislike someone or a certain group it's a feeling or a choice of attitude but translating that into an action is entirely a different order.

Edit: I have been asked to reveal the motive behind this question. I believe it's irrelevant however there is no harm in doing that.

I was merely comparing a religion to an other, Islam for example states for example that we (ie Muslims) should dislike/hate (NOT kill or harm) those who worship idols. I was wondering if there is a similar religious text in Judaism but about Muslims (and maybe Christians?!) since history tells us a little about the conflict between Idolatry and Judaism but a lot about the conflict Judaism and Islam or Christianity

Comment: Why? There is in the Torah something that says "ואהבתם את הגר כי גרים הייתם בארץ מצרים".

Comment: @PichiWuana I don't understand Hebrew

Comment: Some people use this quote as an example where the Torah says to respect the Muslims.  It says "And you loved the migrant because you were migrants in Egypt", if I translate well. In this case it would relate that Jews in Israel should respect arabs in their country. Moreover, there was conflict between idolatry and judaism but that include just a part of jews.

Comment: How can Jewish religious texts have any references to Muslims at all since Muhammad came at least 1000 years after anything in the old testament and several hundred years after completion of Talmud?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no.

We are permitted to hate evildoers. Nonetheless, the Mishna in Avot [Chapter 2](http://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.2.11?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) says (this is a text that contains the spirit of Torah ethics as passed down from God to Moses…) that hatred of people destroys the person who hates.

Also, according to Rambam (Maimonides), even the 7 nations of Canaan and Amalek whom we are commanded to exterminate, were able to surrender and make peace with Israel and even continue to live in the Land of Israel.

I understand from all of this that one should strive to hate only the sin but not the sinner, because the sinner can still change their ways and return to a moral life. Only God knows who is 100% evil. The hatred we are [commanded](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Kings_and_Wars.5.5?qh=%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%A7&lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) to have for Amalek is for the collective race; even so, the individuals can change their ways. The ultimate destruction of evil nations is when the bad ones become good.

Comment: Editing in support for your claims that we're commanded to hate Amalek, that that command doesn't include hatred of individuals, and that Maimonides says those nations could make peace, and explanation of why you cite Maimonides for that if others dissent, would improve your post vastly.

Comment: The verse says to 'remember what amalek did to you' and to 'wipe out their remembrance'. It doesn't say anything about about the individuals. Even if it includes the individuals, we should hate them only until they repent. So, by focusing the hate on the sin or the nation as a whole, we can avoid a 'complete' hatred which may blind us to accepting the repentance of individuals.

Comment: Also, who dissents? The simple reading in the verses in Joshua 11:19-20 is that they are allowed to surrender. The only argument can be whether we offered them peace in the first place or not. But of course they can come on their own accord.

Comment: Re individuals of Amalek: I've never heard that we have to hate them. But I've also never heard we have to hate the nation; you claimed that. If you can cite that, then maybe you can also cite that it doesn't apply to individuals. (Or maybe it'll be clear form the wording.) Re "who dissents": I have no idea. I assumed that from your wording "according to".

Comment: I wrote this as a response to a non-Jew, who also is not a Torah scholar, so I didn't feel obliged to write a whole tshuva on the topic. Also, I don't care about the likes or the reputation. I just want to communicate with people. Take it or leave it :)

Comment: @Emetv'Shalom Thinking that the OP is the only one who will come read this thread seeking answers is so narrow minded it's basically idiotic. Please write posts that will benefit the full readership of this website.

Comment: @Double AA: I think it is too much to expect every answer to be a perfectly written response, especially right away when not all sources are at hand. Also, I do not feel obliged to bring many sources when teaching a non-Jew, because we are not supposed to teach them Torah.

Comment: @Emetv'Shalom You aren't teaching a non-Jew. You are teaching _everyone here_. That's what I just told you was idiotic to think. ||| I don't expect every answer to end up perfect, but that doesn't stop me from encouraging all answers to keep improving, and that shouldn't absolve you from trying to not just slack off.

Comment: Wait a second. What if I hate nazis, antisemites or even Hitler himself. Does the Torah prohibit that?

Comment: @Gabe12: It is permitted and a good thing to hate evil people. I am merely explaining that the hatred should not possess us to the extent that we would not accept their repentance. My advice to prevent that happening is to hate the evil within the person. It is near impossible to see the good in nazis because they revealed their wickedness for all to see. Also, some anti-semites hate us because of rumors or sins we have done and do not make them thoroughly evil, unless they unjustifiably fight us or our Torah.

Answer (score 2):

Disproving a negative is difficult, but I will say that there is no religious text that prescribes disliking or hating Muslims and I will support my assertion with circumstantial evidence.

Throughout history, major Jewish leaders have had good relations with Muslims. [Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) was a physician of the royal family of the [Ayyubid dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayyubid_dynasty). If there was a commandment for Jews to hate Muslims, I believe it is safe to say that such an important religious Jew would not be violating that commandment.

Unfortunately, nowadays, there is definitely animosity in many cases between Jews and Muslims. In my opinion, this can be traced to the political conflict over the Land of Israel that is essentially divided along religious lines. But hate by Jews against Muslims is entirely because of intolerance and not because of any specific religious commandment to hate the other. Just like there are intolerant Muslims who hate Jews simply for being Jews, there are indeed some intolerant Jews who hate Muslims simply for being Muslims. Intolerance based on superficial differences is an ugly trait and is certainly not advocated by the Holy Torah.

Comment: Also, I would suggest that Judaism does distinguish between how we relate to tolerant Moslems and those (e.g. Islamists, Wahhabi, etc.) who hate and incite against us. In fact, the Talmud goes even farther, explicitly encouraging even the hatred of unrepentant sinners (see e.g. Pesachim 113b).

Comment: @Loewian I would agree with that. But the question was about whether Jews are supposed to hate Muslims in general. Of course we differentiate between those who discriminate against us and those who don't regardless of the religion is of the people who discriminate against us.

Comment: @Loewian it's "Muslims" mate, no need to be disrespectful

Comment: @terve. I am asking this because I truly don't know the answer and I want to learn more. Are the names Moslems, Islamists and Wahhabi what you were referring to when you remarked "no need to be disrespectful" or was it the poster's reference to Hadith? Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @JJLL only the fact the he is spelling "Muslims" as "Moslems" , we don't like to be called that. I am not here to discuss Islam and even if I wanted to I wouldn't discuss it with someone who failed to realise that I have made it very clear we are talking about "dislike" NOT actions?! Big difference isn't it?

Comment: @Terve I don't think he meant any disrespect. "Moslem" used to be the accepted English spelling. That has changed over time, but it is still used occasionally without any disrespect intended.

Comment: FYI, @Terve, Daniel's profile lists him as in the United States. Two good [American-English](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Moslem) [dictionaries](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moslem) fail to note that "Moslem" is disrespectful. (But thanks for the tip: I'll try to avoid using it in the future.)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @terve.  I always thought that the difference was simply accent. 'I just searched the net and now realize the difference is significant.

Answer (score -3):

[Avoth 1:12](http://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.12?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) cites an injunction to love all G-d's creatures:

> הִלֵּל אוֹמֵר, הֱוֵי מִתַּלְמִידָיו שֶׁלְאַהֲרֹן, אוֹהֵב שָׁלוֹם וְרוֹדֵף שָׁלוֹם, אוֹהֵב אֶת הַבְּרִיּוֹת וּמְקָרְבָן לַתּוֹרָה
>
> Hillel says, "Be of the disciples of Aharon, loving peace and pursuing peace, loving the creatures and bringing them closer to Torah."

Nonetheless, as opposed to the unconditional love/forgiveness preached by many Christians, and as opposed to the "pluralism" preached by many liberals, Judaism does indeed limit this love and tolerance of mankind. See e.g. Rabbi [M. Soloveichik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_Soloveichik)'s ["The Virtue of Hate](http://www.firstthings.com/article/2003/02/the-virtue-of-hate)":

> ...while no human being is denied the chance to become worthy of God’s love, not every human being engages in actions so as to be worthy of that love, and those unworthy of divine love do not deserve our love either.

Soloveichik further refines that idea, based on the Talmudic passage about the rebuke G-d gave his angels that sought to sing his praise when the Egyptians were drowned in the Red Sea:

> According to the Talmud, the angels began singing a song of triumph upon the deliverance of the Israelites from Egypt until G-d interrupted them: “My creatures are drowning, and you wish to sing a song?” ...Apparently one must cross some terrible moral boundary in order to be a justified target of G-d’s hatred—and of ours. An Israeli mother is right to raise her child to hate Saddam Hussein, but she would fail as a parent if she taught him to despise every Arab.
>
> ...When we are facing those who seek nothing but our destruction, our hate reminds us who we are dealing with. When hate is appropriate, then it is not only virtuous, but essential for Jewish well-being.

Comment: So... are we supposed to hate Muslims? You haven't answered the question.

Comment: @Daniel depends on the Muslim.

Comment: The question wasn't about individual Muslims. It was about Muslims as a whole.

Comment: But  it still does not actually answer the question. Also see the commentaries of the *hated* wife for possible answers. While this is the beginning of an answer, more explanation is needed.